# How can I make a 5mm LED rope using 6v transformer

Tags: led, ac, mains

I want to glow LED using  a 6v AC transformer. I want to add 18 color changing leds (5mm) as series. I cant add  too many wires through the rope (pipe).

See my plan:

[image]

- what are the components I need?
- give a explanation about its circuit
- How to implement this circuit

(Sorry I  am new in handling electronics. But I love it a lot)

Comment: So you want your LEDs in series. In order to use your LEDs you should make a DC voltage from your AC. So the first step will be adding 4 diodes to make it DC. And you'll need a resistor. What are the specs of your LEDs?

Comment: @Handoko there will be 4 colors in that LED and it will be changing in a tone

Comment: How many LEDs do you want to put in series?

Comment: When I know how many LEDs you want to use I can give you a recommendation. How to build and what you need

Comment: @Handoko I want to make it using 18 color changing LEDs.and also  I want to create another one with 18 blue leds(  I want to make it with 5mm LED)

Comment: Which mm LED I have in my hand. (Can you identify from that image)

Comment: Those LEDs look like they're single colour? The RGB ones usually have 4 pins. What LEDs are they?

Comment: I dont know its currect name.but if you need an video proof I will provide.i am buying it by asking color changing led.

Comment: Duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/111786/2028

Comment: @JYelton hello that questions are not same...only images..one is about AC direct main.and another about DC 6v transformer.how it can be same?.there was no one to help me exept russel.and others downvoted me...they says it is a simple question. .if so why they cant answer me?

Comment: If you hover the down-vote arrow, it says, "This question...is unclear or not useful." I expect the down-votes are due to your questions being unclear. You need to provide additional details to make the question answerable. You've mentioned in a comment that you are using 18 LEDs; you can edit the question and include that information.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to put your your LEDs in parallel. To convert your AC input to a DC output you'll need 4 diodes.

Look at the picture:

[image: schematic]

As for R you could calculate your self using the ohms law. " R = U/I " where R is your resistance, U = voltage and I = current. So you'll need just 2 wires in your pipe.

Comment: Each LED needs its own resistor. The LED voltage drops are not going to be identical, so you need a current limiting resistor for each one if you're going to put them in parallel.

Comment: I've changed this now to 1 resistor each. But I think 1 resistor could work fine as well since the current will be divided among the components in parallel and voltage will stay as it is. For a series the voltage will be divided and the current will stay as it is. (Ideal world theory)

Comment: @StaceyAnne :I thank your effort...brother  while adding all the resister to the circut it is no problem...but I dont think that all this LED ,resister , two wire can be injected throgh that small pipe...is it posible to give single resister to ALL LEDs...?

Comment: @Handoko sir, so can I use single resister for all LEDs

Comment: @RAFEEKCJ - Maybe you can, and maybe you can't. If all of the LEDs are ABSOLUTELY identical, you can do it, but they aren't. So, whichever LED pulls the most current for a given voltage will do so. This will cause it to get hotter, and this will cause it to pull more current, etc. In the worst case, it will die, since you have sized the resistor to provide 18 full loads. If it dies open, the next lower voltage LED will have more current available to it (since the first is no longer operating). In the worst case this process kills everything. It's called "firecracker mode failure". You can try.

Answer (score 1):

You can't wire the LEDs in series if you only have a 6V transformer, because the 18 LEDs' forward voltages will add up to much more than the transformer can supply.

Considering a typical color-changing LED to have a forward voltage of about 4 volts with 20 mA through it, you should wire them in parallel, and then your circuit would look something like this:

```
              T1                D1
    MAINS>---+  +---+--[1N5400>]------+----+---------+----//----+
             |  |   |           D2    |    |+        |R1        |R18 
             P||S   +--[<1N5400]--+   | [30000µF]  [150R]     [150R] 
             R||E                 |   |    |C1       |+         |+
             I||C   +--[<1N5400]--+---|----+       [LED]      [LED]
             |  |   |           D3    |    |         |LED1      |LED18
    MAINS>---+  +---+--[1N5400>]------+    +---------+----//----+  
                                D4
```

T1 is your transformer, which has a 6VRMS secondary and a primary rated for your mains voltage and frequency, D1, D2, D3, and D4 are 50 volt, 3 ampere rectifiers wired to comprise a full-wave bridge, C1 is the reservoir capacitor required to keep a steady DC voltage available for your LEDs, R1 --> R18 are the current limiting resistors for the LEDs, LED1 --> LED18 are the color-changing LEDs, and here's how it works:

Starting at the tail end of the circuit, each of the LEDs is set up to draw about 20mA, so 18 of them in parallel will draw 20mA per LED times 18 LEDs = 360mA.

The transformer must supply that current, plus the current required to charge up C1 at the peaks of the rectified AC, so a good rule of thumb for the secondary's average total current rating is about 1.8 times the load current which, in this case, would be about 650mA.

The RMS (Root Mean Square) value of the transformer's voltage (and/or current) is determined by the transformer's ability to heat a load to the same temperature that a DC source would, and because of the peaks and valleys of the AC waveform, the peaks must rise to 1.414 times the voltage that a DC source would.

That means that a transformer with a 6 volt RMS secondary will output a sinusoid with about 8.5 volt high negative and positive peaks.

Then, as those peaks travel through the bridge, they'll suffer a loss of two diode drops, with the effect being that C1 can only charge up to about 7 volts instead of 8.5.

Now, since we have C1 charged up to 7 volts and the LEDs want to see 4 volts across them with 20 mA through them, we must drop that extra 3 volts.

To do that, we connect series current-limiting resistors between C1 and each of the LEDs, and determine their value using Ohm's law:

```
         E        3V
    R = ---  = ------- = 150 ohms
         I      0.02A
```

Since each resistor will drop 3 volts with 20 mA through it, each will dissipate:

```
    P = I²R = 0.02A² * 150R = 0.06 watts,
```

so common 150 ohm +/-5%, 1/8 or 1/4 watt carbon film resistors wired into the harness will work.

To figure out the value of C1, we can use:

```
         It
    C = ----
         dV
```

where C is the required capacitance, in farads
      I is the load current in amperes
      t is the period of the rectified AC waveform, and
      dV is the allowable ripple voltage, in volts.

Assuming 60 Hz mains and setting the allowable ripple to 0.1 volt gives us:

```
         0.36A * 0.00833s
    C = ------------------ = 0.03 farad = 30000 microfarads
               0.1V
```

Larger ripple will allow smaller caps to be used, the limit being what the LEDs can stand and still change colors properly.

A caveat:  Before committing to buy parts, load the transformer with about 650 mA, measure its output voltage, and adjust the LED current limiting resistors if necessary.

Comment: Sir, can I do this as series by using a 12v transformer.can you provide me circut digram of series and parallel connection

Comment: If the LEDs each drop 4V when there's 20mA through them, and you have 18 LEDs in series, then you'll need at least 18 * 4V = 72 volts, DC to drive them.

Comment: I think it would be much clearer to use the schematic tool rather than to draw ASCII art.